# javascript innerhtml returning one result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, innerhtml

1. When I click the checkbox, only the first row shows the text box.

   **Expected** When  I check the checkbox, the text box will show in that row.
2. When i click the submit button, it only inserts the data from the first row.

   **Example** When I checked 3 boxes, it will insert the data from the first row 3 times.

How can I fix my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(codeasset){
          if(codeasset.checked){

        document.getElementById('hotStuff').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="hotStuff" style="width: 150px;" />';

    }else {
        document.getElementById('hotStuff').innerHTML='';
    }}
</script>


<?php

     $assets_supplier_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_assets WHERE status = '0' AND supplier_id = '$supplier_id'");

      while ($get_supplier_asset = mysql_fetch_array($assets_supplier_query))
                                {

        $asset_code = $get_supplier_asset['asset_code'];
        $asset_qty = $get_supplier_asset['supply_quantity'];

        $asset_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ref_assetmodel WHERE modelID = '$asset_code' ");
        $get_asset = mysql_fetch_array($asset_query);
        $asset_model = $get_asset['assetModel'];
        $specifications = $get_asset['specifications'];
        $category_id = $get_asset['categoryID'];
        $type_id = $get_asset['typeID'];

        $category_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ref_assetcategory WHERE categoryID = '$category_id' ORDER BY categoryID");
        $get_category = mysql_fetch_array($category_query);
        $category = $get_category['assetCategory'];

        $type_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ref_assettype WHERE typeID = '$type_id' ");
        $get_type = mysql_fetch_array($type_query);
        $type = $get_type['assetType'];
?>

<form action="../process/approve_supplies_process.php" method="post" name="supplier">

       <td><input type="checkbox" id="codeasset" name="supply[]" onclick="changeText(this)" value="<?php echo $asset_code ?>">&nbsp;</td>

        <td name="supply[]"><?php echo $type; ?></td>
        <td name="supply[]"><?php echo $asset_model; ?></td>
        <td name="supply[]"><?php echo $asset_qty; ?></td>
        <td name="supply[]" id="hotStuff" value="<?php echo $asset_code ?>"></td>

        <?php

                    }
        ?>

      <tr>

           <td align="center"><input type="submit" class="edit_butt" name="action" value="Submit" onclick=""></td>

            <input type="hidden" name="supplier_id" value="<?php echo $supplier_id; ?>">          

        </tr> 
     </form>




<?php
        $asset_code = $_POST['asset_code'];
        $categoryID = $_POST['category_id'];
        $type_id = $_POST['type_id'];
        $supplier_id = $_POST['supplier_id'];

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $inventoryDate= date("Y-m-d");

        if(isset($_POST['supply'])){


            foreach ($_POST['supply'] as $_value)
            {
                echo "Box #{$_value} was selected!\n";
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_inventory(inventoryDate, categoryID, typeID, modelID, serialNumber, qrCode, is_owned, supplier_id)
                VALUES('$inventoryDate', '$categoryID', '$type_id', '$asset_code', '954', '', 1, '$supplier_id') ");
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: id name `id="hotStuff"` not supposed to have more than one element with the same name. You should use css class or unique id name for looping table column.

Comment: Improved question text and code snippet